# How can files be added to a tarfile with Python, without adding the directory hierarchy?

Tags: python, tar

When I invoke `add()` on a `tarfile` object with a file path, the file is added to the tarball with directory hierarchy associated. In other words, if I unzip the tarfile the directories in the original directories hierarchy are reproduced.

Is there a way to simply add a plain file, without directory info, so that untarring the resulting tarball produces a flat list of files?

Comment: For those that need to keep ***part*** of the directory structure, have a look at `shutil.make_archive()`, specifically the `root_dir` and `base_dir` arguments. See [example in docs](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/shutil.html#shutil-archiving-example-with-basedir) and e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32640053).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use [`tarfile.addfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/tarfile-objects.html), in the [`TarInfo`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/tarinfo-objects.html) object, which is the first parameter, you can specify a `name` that's different from the file you're adding.

This piece of code should add `/path/to/filename` to the TAR file but will extract it as `myfilename`:

```
tar.addfile(tarfile.TarInfo("myfilename.txt"), open("/path/to/filename.txt"))
```

Comment: Also, it also works for `tar.add()`! To add whole tree, but with a diferent name, just do: `tar.add('/path/to/dir/to/add/', arcname='newdirname')` and then the tarfile will contain a directory with named 'newdirname', and with all it's contents untouched.

Comment: And if you want to save the files without all the directory structure. do `arcname='.'`

Comment: What is this file() function? How to import it?

Comment: `file()` is Python 2 only, `open()` is equivalent and works in both Python 2 and 3. I edited my answer to use `open` instead.

Comment: For some reason in my machine this creates only tar archive with empty files (the files are there, but empty).

Comment: Using `arcname='.'` gave me a `IsADirectoryError` when I tried to unzip and extract the content. Using the answer by @diabloneo below worked though.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas You might have forgotten the second argument to `addfile` like me. You'll need to do `tar.addfile( tar.gettarinfo( filename ), open( filename, 'rb' ) )` or `tarfile.add( filename )` like in the other answer.

Answer (score 110):

Using the **arcname** argument of TarFile.add() method is an alternate and convenient way to match your destination.

Example: you want to archive a dir *repo/a.git/* to a *tar.gz* file, but you rather want the tree root in the archive begins by *a.git/* but not *repo/a.git/*, you can do like followings:

```
archive = tarfile.open("a.git.tar.gz", "w|gz")
archive.add("repo/a.git", arcname="a.git")
archive.close()
```

Comment: This is a better approach since the accepted answer will not work if you are trying to add directories.

Comment: `arcname ="a.git"` will create a folder `a.git` inside the archive. You can use `arcname =""` to archive files in the `repo/a.git` directory without creating a folder.

Comment: @ComradeChe 's answer gives wrong result: resulting tar contains then just single file.
Instead provide clear filename (without path) as arcname for each file added into the tar.

Comment: on the contrary, i think ComradeChe's answer is correct, @Alexey Antonenko could you provide an example?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can use the "arcname" argument to TarFile.add(name, arcname). It takes an alternate name that the file will have inside the archive.

Answer (score 3):

thanks to @diabloneo, function to create selective tarball of a dir

```
def compress(output_file="archive.tar.gz", output_dir='', root_dir='.', items=[]):
    """compress dirs.

    KWArgs
    ------
    output_file : str, default ="archive.tar.gz"
    output_dir : str, default = ''
        absolute path to output
    root_dir='.',
        absolute path to input root dir
    items : list
        list of dirs/items relative to root dir

    """
    os.chdir(root_dir)
    with tarfile.open(os.path.join(output_dir, output_file), "w:gz") as tar:
        for item in items:
            tar.add(item, arcname=item)    


>>>root_dir = "/abs/pth/to/dir/"
>>>compress(output_file="archive.tar.gz", output_dir=root_dir, 
            root_dir=root_dir, items=["logs", "output"])
```

Comment: You should always guard a os.chdir with try finally going back to the old working directory as library code isn't expected to change the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code sample to tar list of files in `folder` without adding folder:

```
    with tarfile.open(tar_path, 'w') as tar:
        for filename in os.listdir(folder):
            fpath = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            tar.add(fpath, arcname=filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for similar question but got redirected to this page so I might add this for further fellow googlers.
In my case, I want to have a tar file with only relative file names inside of it, which would work recursively. So, a zippable directory of

```
/home/test/data
/home/test/data/content.txt
/home/test/data/files/file.txt
```

in zip would look like this:

```
content.txt
files/file.txt
```

By default, python `tarfile` will add `/` as extra entry.

My goal was to remove leading `/` entry in tar file, since it is considered an [ZipSlip vulnerability](https://security.snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability)

When using tar with such vulnerability you will get an warning

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

I'm not sure why python `tarfile` library does not have easy way to handle this, but I came up with this code that does exactly what I want:

```
def package_tar_recursive_without_root_folder(input_dir: str, output_file: str):
    with tarfile.open(output_file, mode='w:gz') as archive:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
            for file in files:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                relative_path = os.path.relpath(file_path, input_dir)
                archive.add(file_path, arcname=relative_path, recursive=False)
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to add the directory name but not its contents inside a tarfile, you can do the following:

(1) create an empty directory called `empty`
(2) `tf.add("empty", arcname=path_you_want_to_add)`

That creates an empty directory with the name `path_you_want_to_add`.

Comment: The original post asked to include file(s) with no directory. Your answer answers a different question. Please modify your answer to answer the original post’s question. Or add this as a comment instead of an answer.