# Use python tarfile add without normpath being applied to arcname

Tags: python, tar

I'm using python's tarfile library to create a gzipped tar file.

The tar file needs to have absolute pathnames for reasons that I've got no control over. (I'm aware that this isn't normal practice.)

When I call

```
tarobject.add("/foo/xx1", "/bar/xx1")
```

the arcname argument "/bar/xx1" is run through os.path.normpath() and converted to "bar/xx1"

How do I avoid this and end up with "/bar/xx1" as I require?

I've read that I can replace normpath somewhere, but I'm fairly new to Python and I'm not sure how to do this or what the wider implications would be.

**edit**

After looking [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239655/python-tarfile-adding-files-without-directory-hiearchy) I had a closer look at the tarinfo object, and this seems to work:

```
my_tarinfo = tarobject.gettarinfo("/foo/xx1")
my_tarinfo.name = "/bar/xx1"
tarobject.addfile(my_tarinfo, file("/foo/xx1"))
```

Comment: While the file is actually added with the first slash removed, it isn't os.path.normpath who removes it. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @deStrangis: looking at tarfile.py it's in gettarinfo. I'll see if I can find a workaround with the object this creates.

Answer (score -1):

You really do strange things. You need to copy `/usr/lib64/python/tarfile.py` to a directory in your PYTHONPATH. Then you can modify this file. But you need to bundle you own tarfile module with your code.

Comment: Was hoping I could do some kind of monkey patch along the lines of tarfile.normpath = lambda path: path   but this doesn't seem to work.