# Extract all files with directory path in given directory

Tags: python, extract, tar

I have a tar archive in which I have a directory which I need to extract in a given directory.
For example: I have a directory

> TarPrefix/x/y/z

in a tar archive I want to extract it in a given target directory for example: extracted/a/ this directory should contain all the files and directories contained in directory TarPrefix/x/y/z.

```
subdir_and_files = [  tarinfo for tarinfo in tar.getmembers()
                      if tarinfo.name.startswith("subfolder/")
                   ]
```

to get the list of all the members in the directory path "subfolder/" and then I extract it using `tar.extractall(extracted/a,subdir_and_files)`
but it extracts all the members with their directory path For example this results in  extracted/a/x/y/z.
Could you please help me in extracting these files in the given folder.

Comment: I don't know, but this question seems to be sort of the opposite of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239655/python-tarfile-adding-files-without-directory-hiearchy  Maybe you can use extract() rather than extractall() and see what you can make happen, possibly by modifying the TarInfo objects you got in subdir_and_files?

Comment: Sorry to ask a beginner's question. I am a beginner in python and did not found any answer on google that's why asked such a question. To help others I want to answer this question.

You just need to change the tarinfo.name attribute value to the correct value. i.e. in my given example `tarinfo.name=tarinfo.name[len(Tarprefix/x/y/z):]` and then using the same code works.

Comment: I tried to answer my own question but I am not allowed till eight hours so was waiting till then.

Comment: I think the answer is not easy, the way how it [tarlib] is done it not good (tarinfo tells about object in archive, not about extracted object). I think it should be better api for extracting stuff (tar command for example has --strip-components parameter)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like you may have already found an answer, but here's my version anyway:

```
import sys, tarfile

def get_members(tar, prefix):
    if not prefix.endswith('/'):
        prefix += '/'
    offset = len(prefix)
    for tarinfo in tar.getmembers():
        if tarinfo.name.startswith(prefix):
            tarinfo.name = tarinfo.name[offset:]
            yield tarinfo

args = sys.argv[1:]

if len(args) > 1:
    tar = tarfile.open(args[0])
    path = args[2] if len(args) > 2 else '.'
    tar.extractall(path, get_members(tar, args[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Ya I found the answer by experimenting with stuff :). Anyways thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

```
with tarfile.open('sourcefile.tgz', 'r:gz') as _tar:
    for member in _tar:
      if member.isdir():
         continue
      fname = member.name.rsplit('/',1)[1]
      _tar.makefile(member, 'desination_dir' + '/' + fname)
```

Comment: describe something about your answer.

Comment: You should probably change `member.name.rsplit('/',1)[1]` with `member.name.rsplit('/')[-1]` - in case the path (`member.name`) doesn't contain a directory.