# Extracting only a specific subfolder 7zip

Tags: python, 7zip

I'm working on a python script that will automatically update Calibre since it does not contain an autoupdater and updates weekly.  My script downloads the portable zip file, and then should extract a specific subfolder of the zip file (I don't need all the files).

What I have so far:

`os.system("7z x install.zip -y -r -oc:\\\"Program Files (x86)\\\"Calibre2");`

This works for everything except downloading the specific sub directory I need.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As given in [How to partially extract a folder from a 7z file using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195959/how-to-partially-extract-a-folder-from-a-7z-file-using-powershell):

```
os.system("7z x install.zip subfolder -y -r -oc:\\\"Program Files (x86)\\\"Calibre2")
```

should be ok for you

Answer (score 0):

Below is a zip version of a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8261083/984421) I gave for tar files.

Usage:

```
unzipdir.py path/to/zipfile zip/folder [output/folder]
```

Script:

```
import sys, os
from zipfile import ZipFile

def get_members(zip, prefix):
    if not prefix.endswith('/'):
        prefix += '/'
    offset = len(prefix)
    for zipinfo in zip.infolist():
        name = zipinfo.filename
        if len(name) > offset:
            zipinfo.filename = name[offset:]
            yield zipinfo

args = sys.argv[1:]

if len(args):
    zip = ZipFile(args[0])
    path = args[2] if len(args) > 2 else '.'
    zip.extractall(path, get_members(zip, args[1]))
```

Comment: @Jacobm001. I tested my script on the [latest calibre version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/calibre/files/), and it works fine (it only took a few seconds to extract the 128Mb `/Calibre Portable/Calibre` folder). So 7zip is not needed.