# Compressing directory using shutil.make_archive() while preserving directory structure

Tags: python, directory, zip, shutil

I'm trying to zip a directory called `test_dicoms` to a zip file named `test_dicoms.zip` using the following code:

```py
shutil.make_archive('/home/code/test_dicoms', 'zip', '/home/code/test_dicoms')
```

The problem is that when I unzip it, all of the files that were in `/test_dicoms/` are extracted to `/home/code/` instead of the folder `/test_dicoms/` and all of it's contained files being extracted to `/home/code/`. So `/test_dicoms/` has a file called `foo.txt` and after I zip and unzip `foo.txt`'s path is `/home/code/foo.txt` as opposed to `/home/code/test_dicoms/foo.txt`. How do I fix this? Also, some of the directories I'm working with are very large. Will I need to add anything to my code to make it ZIP64 or is the function smart enough to do that automatically?

Here's what's currently in the archive created:

```
[gwarner@jazz gwarner]$ unzip -l test_dicoms.zip
Archive: test_dicoms.zip
Length    Date       Time  Name
--------- ---------- ----- ----
    93324 09-17-2015 16:05 AAscout_b_000070
    93332 09-17-2015 16:05 AAscout_b_000125
    93332 09-17-2015 16:05 AAscout_b_000248
```

Comment: Please provide a copy-paste of the zip directory. For example, if you are on Linux, run `unzip -l test_dicoms.zip`.

Comment: `[gwarner@jazz gwarner]$ unzip -l test_dicoms.zip

Archive:  test_dicoms.zip

 Length      Date    Time    Name

---------  ---------- -----   ----

    93324  09-17-2015 16:05   AAscout_b_000070

    93332  09-17-2015 16:05   AAscout_b_000125

    93332  09-17-2015 16:05   AAscout_b_000248`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Using the terms in the documentation, you have specified a *root_dir*, but not a *base_dir*. Try specifying the *base_dir* like so:

```
shutil.make_archive('/home/code/test_dicoms',
                    'zip',
                    '/home/code/',
                    'test_dicoms')
```

To answer your second question, it depends upon the version of Python you are using. Starting from Python 3.4, ZIP64 extensions will be availble by default. Prior to Python 3.4, `make_archive` will not automatically create a file with ZIP64 extensions. If you are using an older version of Python and want ZIP64, you can invoke the underlying `zipfile.ZipFile()` directly.

If you choose to use `zipfile.ZipFile()` directly, bypassing `shutil.make_archive()`, here is an example:

```
import zipfile
import os

d = '/home/code/test_dicoms'

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(d))
with zipfile.ZipFile(d + '.zip',
                     "w",
                     zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,
                     allowZip64=True) as zf:
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(os.path.basename(d)):
        for name in filenames:
            name = os.path.join(root, name)
            name = os.path.normpath(name)
            zf.write(name, name)
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive
- https://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects

Comment: Please clarify you mean by "invoke the underlying `zipfile.ZipFile()` directly"?

Comment: a note that python 3.4+ has shutil supporting zip64 by default http://bugs.python.org/issue17189

Comment: But `ZipFile` does not support gzip.

Answer (score 27):

I have written a wrapper function myself because `shutil.make_archive` is too confusing to use.

Here it is http://www.seanbehan.com/how-to-use-python-shutil-make_archive-to-zip-up-a-directory-recursively-including-the-root-folder/

And just the code..

```
import os, shutil
def make_archive(source, destination):
        base = os.path.basename(destination)
        name = base.split('.')[0]
        format = base.split('.')[1]
        archive_from = os.path.dirname(source)
        archive_to = os.path.basename(source.strip(os.sep))
        shutil.make_archive(name, format, archive_from, archive_to)
        shutil.move('%s.%s'%(name,format), destination)

make_archive('/path/to/folder', '/path/to/folder.zip')
```

Comment: Have you run any timing / compression tests on this against using `os.walk()` and `zipfile`?  Your function is great, but it defeats the simplicity of shutil's own `make_archive()` - not your fault, just a shortcoming of shutil.

Comment: No, I haven't done any benchmarking. I just found `make_archive()` to be very difficult to use.. never being able to remember the correct order of the args. Input folder and output file seems to be all that's needed, imo.

Comment: Could you check my answer and see if this is doing the same thing without the file moving?

Answer (score 6):

I think, I am able to improve seanbehan's answer by removing the file moving:

```
def make_archive(source, destination):
    base_name = '.'.join(destination.split('.')[:-1])
    format = destination.split('.')[-1]
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(source)
    base_dir = os.path.basename(source.strip(os.sep))
    shutil.make_archive(base_name, format, root_dir, base_dir)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are basically 2 approaches to using `shutil`: you may try to understand the logic behind it or you may just use an example. I couldn't find an example here so I tried to create my own.

;TLDR. Run `shutil.make_archive('dir1_arc', 'zip',  root_dir='dir1')` or `shutil.make_archive('dir1_arc', 'zip', base_dir='dir1')` or just `shutil.make_archive('dir1_arc', 'zip',  'dir1')` from `temp`.

Suppose you have `~/temp/dir1`:

```
temp $ tree dir1
dir1
├── dir11
│   ├── file11
│   ├── file12
│   └── file13
├── dir1_arc.zip
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3
```

How can you create an archive of `dir1`? Set `base_name='dir1_arc'`, `format='zip'`. Well you have *a lot*  of options:

- `cd` into `dir1` and run `shutil.make_archive(base_name=base_name, format=format)`; it will create an archive `dir1_arc.zip` inside `dir1`; the only problem you'll get a strange behavior: inside your archive you'll find file `dir1_arc.zip`;
- from `temp` run `shutil.make_archive(base_name=base_name, format=format, base_dir='dir1')`; you'll get `dir1_arc.zip` inside `temp` that you can unzip into `dir1`; `root_dir` defaults to `temp`;
- from `~` run `shutil.make_archive(base_name=base_name, format=format, root_dir='temp', base_dir='dir1')`; you'll again get your file but this time inside `~` directory;
- create another directory `temp2` in `~` and run inside it: `shutil.make_archive(base_name=base_name, format=format, root_dir='../temp', base_dir='dir1')`; you'll get your archive in this `temp2` folder;

Can you run `shutil` without specifying arguments? You can. Run from `temp` `shutil.make_archive('dir1_arc', 'zip',  'dir1')`. This is the same as run `shutil.make_archive('dir1_arc', 'zip',  root_dir='dir1')`. What can we say about `base_dir` in this case? From documentation not so much. From source code we may see that:

```
if root_dir is not None:
  os.chdir(root_dir)

if base_dir is None:
        base_dir = os.curdir
```

So in our case `base_dir` is `dir1`. And we can keep asking questions.

Answer (score 4):

I was having issues with path split on some paths with '.' periods in them and i found having an optional format which defaults to 'zip' is handy and still allows you to override for other formats and is less error prone.

```
import os
import shutil
from shutil import make_archive

def make_archive(source, destination, format='zip'):
    import os
    import shutil
    from shutil import make_archive
    base, name = os.path.split(destination)
    archive_from = os.path.dirname(source)
    archive_to = os.path.basename(source.strip(os.sep))
    print(f'Source: {source}\nDestination: {destination}\nArchive From: {archive_from}\nArchive To: {archive_to}\n')
    shutil.make_archive(name, format, archive_from, archive_to)
    shutil.move('%s.%s' % (name, format), destination)
```

```
make_archive('/path/to/folder', '/path/to/folder.zip')
```

Special thanks to seanbehan's original answer or i would have been lost in the sauce much longer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on @nick's answer that uses `pathlib`, type hinting and avoids shadowing builtins:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

def make_archive(source: Path, destination: Path) -> None:
    base_name = destination.parent / destination.stem
    fmt = destination.suffix.replace(".", "")
    root_dir = source.parent
    base_dir = source.name
    shutil.make_archive(str(base_name), fmt, root_dir, base_dir)
```

Usage:

```py
make_archive(Path("/path/to/dir/"), Path("/path/to/output.zip"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pathlib` and `shutil`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import shutil
shutil.make_archive(
   *dest_path.split('.'), 
   root_dir=Path(src_path).parent, 
   base_dir=Path(src_path).name)
)
```

- `src_path` is the path of the source directory.
- `dest_path` is the path of the destination archive to be created.

Answer (score 0):

This solution builds off the responses from irudyak and seanbehan and uses `Pathlib`. You need to pass `source` and `destination` as Path objects.

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

def make_archive(source, destination):
    base_name = destination.parent / destination.stem
    format = (destination.suffix).replace(".", "")
    root_dir = source.parent
    base_dir = source.name
    shutil.make_archive(base_name, format, root_dir, base_dir)
```