# Python script is dependent of another .exe. Is it possible to merge both into one single .exe?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, tar

I am writing a short `script.py` which will update `archive.tar`. 
The tar archive's content is one single file: `file.txt (Content: "Hello")`.
I am using `7za.exe` which is the the command line version of 7zip to update `file.txt` with another `file.txt (Content: "Hello world")`. I am using the following command:

`os.system("7za u archive.tar file.txt")`

So far everything is working, however I would like to create an executable from the Python Script using PyInstaller, since not everyone using this script will have python installed.

My question: is there a way to merge both `script.py` and `7za.exe` into one single .exe file?
So far, I have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply using the [ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/zipfile.html) library?

This could be as simple as:

```
with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('eggs.txt')
```

If you really want to use a third party then no, there is no simple way of doing what you want to do. The only "clean" way would be to pack your executables together by using an installer, like the ones you could create with [Innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

> NB: You should prefer the use of subprocess rather that `os.system`, see there https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system

**Update**: For a tarfile, maybe these could help you:

- [How to append a file to a tar file use python tarfile module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361665/how-to-append-a-file-to-a-tar-file-use-python-tarfile-module)
- [How can files be added to a tarfile with Python, without adding the directory hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239655/how-can-files-be-added-to-a-tarfile-with-python-without-adding-the-directory-hi)

Maybe you'll have to decompress / add / recompress, but you should be able to do it in memory.

Comment: I am guessing ZipFile will not work, since my archive is a .tar and not a .zip.
I have tried using tarfile, too, but there is no option to update a file inside the archive, only to create a new one. Even the bsdtar command on Windows 10 won't let me update files... Only way I managed to do it until now was with 7zip.
I would prefer not to build an installer, and instead just keep it as an exe which can be passed around.
And I made a note to change from os.system to subprocess when I get this problem solved ;)

Comment: Ah yeah, my bad, I did not spot the .tar at first. See my updates